# How to make this jQuery ajax function work with jQuery 1.12.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some ajax function with jQuery 1.5.x, i need upgrade to jQuery 1.12.x but this jquery function not working.

```
function vpb_add_to_cart(post_title,post_id,guid,status)
{
    $("div.checkout_user_info").hide();
    $("div#checkout_user_info").hide();
    $("div.shopping_cart_status").show();
    $("div#shopping_cart_status").show();

    var dataString = "post_title=" + post_title + "&post_id=" + post_id + "&guid=" + guid + "&page=add_to_cart";
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "http://localhost/www/opsional/wp-compare.php",  
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
            $("#response").html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading..."> Loading...<br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />');
        },  
        success: function(response)
        {
            $("#response").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Pickup data with this;

```
<input type="button" id="vasplus_p_blog_add_to_cart_button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add this item to cart" onclick="vpb_add_to_cart('Samsung Galaxy Note 3','2688','http://localhost/www/opsional/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Samsung-Galaxy-Note-3-2-4-150x150.jpg','add');" />
```

How to make all above code work with jQuery 1.12.x
Thanks, please help.

Comment: That works already with `1.12.x` Why?

Comment: Which part of that doesn't work? What does it do in 1.5 and what does it do in 1.12? Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @JJJ have this error **$ is not a function in line** `$("div.checkout_user_info").hide();`

Comment: Well that means that you haven't included jQuery correctly. That doesn't have anything to do with the code you've shown.

Comment: @JJJ after check, jQuery correctly added before function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a problem with your JavaScript, but rather with the instantiation of jQuery. You may have multiple instances of jQuery on the page, or you may possibly have an issue returning the jQuery library. If you're getting a message about the $ itself then the problem lies outside of your function.

I would make sure that you're not loading a second version of jQuery and that you're not loading a library that might compete with jQuery and/or take over the $.

You could test this by replacing your "$" indicators with "jQuery" instead.

Comment: Nice! Work perfect with replace "$" to "jQuery" , thanks.

Comment: please help agan. Below my questions